# Parametrize the saddle surface

Tags: vector-analysis, parametrization

[image]

[image]

How do I show that Ψ is one-to-one?

Comment: what happens if $a \neq 0,$ with $a^2 = u^2,$ $a \cosh b = u \cosh v,$ and $a \sinh b = u \sinh v \; \; ?$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:-
$$ Ψ(u_1,v_1)= Ψ(u_2,v_2)$$
$\implies u_1\cosh v_1=u_2\cosh v_2$ and $u_1\cosh v_1=u_2\cosh v_2$ and $u_1^2=u_2^2$
$$\implies \frac{u_1}{u_2}=\frac{\sinh v_1}{\sinh v_2}=\frac{\cosh v_1}{\cosh v_2}
$$

$$\implies \sinh (v_1-v_2)=0$$